# How do I structure a review ratings database?

Tags: mysql

I am aware of this post, but I feel my question is slightly different and less complex.

[MySQL rating database structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024988/mysql-rating-database-structure)

If I have fifty different items and I want to make a ratings database for these items is it simply a matter of having an id column and a score column?

So each time a new rating is entered, the id of the item and the rating makes a new row in the database.

Then when I want to query the results for an individual item, I simply query `"WHERE id =xyz "` and then average out the ratings or do whatever I need to do with the item.

Over time I would just end up with a huge database of Id's and ratings I guess that seems kind of sloppy, but giving each item and individual column etc obviously is massive overkill.

Or, is there a better approach that I missing or other things I am not considering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want a `rater` column so that the same person can't submit multiple ratings. If you're not going to use logins, you can use a random string that's saved in a cookie.  When someone tries to submit a rating, you check for the cookie.  If the cookie exists, you either overwrite the old rating or disallow re-rating, however you wish to handle it. If it doesn't exist, you generate the random string and save it in the cookie.

If you don't need to keep track of each individual rating, you could do it all with just two columns in a per-item table. The columns would be `avg_rating` and `num_ratings`. When a new rating is submitted, you can update the avergage rating with the following formula:

```
UPDATE item_table
SET avg_rating = @new_rating/(num_ratings+1) + avg_rating*(num_ratings/(num_ratings+1)),
    num_ratings = num_ratings + 1
WHERE item_id = @item
```

Comment: Very nice thank you. And if I decide to screen raters, what is your preferred method? $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] or something similar? Session ID seems like it could be thwarted.

Comment: To prevent thwarting you need to require a login, although preventing the same user from creating multiple accounts would be difficult. Session ID is useless since sessions only last a few minutes. Without a login you can use cookies, but they can clear cookies.

Comment: a login would be too much for this system unfortunately...we want the user to be able to rate with extreme ease. I think a cookie would be fine and even if the best I could do was restrict it to one rating per browsing session that would be more than fine for this system.

Comment: Updated answer with how to use a cookie for tracking raters.